# Java NIO Issue on CharBuffer

Tags: java, nio

I am using following code to read a sub-sequence from a file.

```
FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile("abc.txt", "r").getChannel();
ByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
CharBuffer cbuf = buffer.asCharBuffer();

String str = cbuf.subSequence(0, 1).toString();
System.out.println("str = " + str);
```

However, this gives output "str = ?" Can anybody help me why is this happening and how to solve this ? Sorry, I am new in NIO.

Additional thing, when I add System.out.println(buffer); it gives output "java.nio.DirectByteBufferR[pos=0 lim=16 cap=16]".

System.out.println((char)buffer.get(0)) gives proper output means 1st character.

Comment: What is the content of `abc.txt`?

Comment: @Jeffrey, "011000111......" series of 0/1 bits.

Comment: @Jeffrey, additional thing when I add System.out.println(buffer) it gives output, "java.nio.DirectByteBufferR[pos=0 lim=16 cap=16]"

Comment: Is it possible that the file is in some sort of Unicode encoding?

Comment: @Attila, I have modified my question. Hope it will clear more about issue.

Comment: @Jeffrey, I have modified my question. Hope it will clear more about issue.

Comment: You are describing the file as if it were a binary file and not a text file. If so you really don't want to try to read it as if it were a text file.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, the file is a text file with characters 0 and 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this method, you have an encoding issue :

```
    FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile("/home/alain/Bureau/clair.txt", "r").getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
    Charset chars = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
    CharBuffer cbuf = chars.decode(buffer);
    String str = cbuf.subSequence(0, 10).toString();
    System.out.println("str = " + str);
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I add some modification in my question. Is it possible to work the above code ? Actually, I want to extract sub-strings. I think above code will be less efficient.

Comment: @Arpssss You are in read only mode so I guess it's better to use `asReadOnlyBuffer`. I made some test on my computer with `asCharBuffer` I only get 1/2 byte.

Comment: I tested my code. Actually, the issue happens while doing "CharBuffer cbuf = buffer.asCharBuffer()". Maybe some encoding issue.

Comment: Yes, I was looking on it check this solution. ;)